# I am trying to create Navbar using Bootsrap 5 in react js but my dropdown button not working

Tags: reactjs, navbar

```
import React from 'react'
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
```

Comment: It would be best if you could add the code, some screenshots or the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code might help you, as this is exactly what I'm using.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    Navbar,
    Nav,
    NavDropdown,
    Dropdown,
    DropdownButton,
    Image,
    Button,
} from "react-bootstrap";

import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


function Header(props) {
    const history = useHistory();


    return (
        <>
            
                <Navbar
                    collapseOnSelect
                    expand="lg"
                    bg="link"
                    variant="light"
                    style={{ boxShadow: "0 0 10px 0 rgb(88 96 109 / 14%" }}
                    className="align-items-center"
                >
                    <Navbar.Brand className="mr-auto" as={Link} to="/">
                        <Image src="/images/logo.png" width="150px" fluid />
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="ml-auto">
                            {isCompany ? (
                                <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/publish/ticket">
                                    Submit Ticker
                                </Nav.Link>
                            ) : (
                                <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/tickers">
                                    Find Tickets
                                </Nav.Link>
                            )}
                            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/dashboard">
                                <Button
                                    className="text-center"
                                    type="submit"
                                    size="sm"
                                    variant="primary"
                                >
                                    Dashboard
                                </Button>
                            </Nav.Link>

                            <Nav.Link as="span">
                                <DropdownButton
                                    id="dropdown-basic-button"
                                    title="Profile"
                                    variant="success"
                                    size="sm"
                                    menuAlign="right"
                                >
                                    <Dropdown.Item as={Link} to="/edit/profile">
                                        Edit Profile
                                    </Dropdown.Item>
                                    <NavDropdown.Divider />
                                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={logMeOut}>Logout</Dropdown.Item>
                                </DropdownButton>
                            </Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
        
        </>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with removing "../node_modules"

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

This code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys....issue resolved after update my bootstrap version 5.0.0 to 5.0.2.